# Is Harvard style used in business?

Tags: citations, citation-style

Most websites mention that APA is preferred for the business and management disciplines, and resources regarding Harvard as not as widespread as APA.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as a researcher working in industry, I have seen no particular pattern in the citation style used by people working in corporations.  It tends to default into whatever they are used to, whatever comes most easily to them, whatever their citation manager happens to be set on, whatever arbitrary thing corporate policy has settled upon, or whatever arbitrary thing is being required by the external organization they are interacting with (just like inside of academia).

Comment: Alright. There seems to also be an issue with the usage of 'ibid.'. In APA and as far as I know, it is not used. However, it is still used in the more general 'author-date' citation style (i.e. Harvard?), what do you think? I want to be able to combine Harvard style (not APA) + ibid. usage (since I tend to overcite).

Comment: @R.AS. Who are you writing the document for?  If it's just for yourself, you can do whatever you want. If you want truly compact citation, though, I recommend a style like IEEE.

Comment: University assignments between essays and the upcoming master's thesis. Frankly, I don't have much time to learn a new style now (at least before my master's thesis writing) so I want to finish whatever essays due now using the style I mastered and memorized well (i.e. Harvard), it's just that most online sites recommend APA for business instead of Harvard (and the usage of ibid. is acceptable in the latter) so I don't want to be in a position in the future where someone says: 'oh you used Harvard in your business studies, it isn't acceptable, you should have used APA'.

Comment: @R.AS. If your school doesn't care what format you use, I would recommend simply using what you are most comfortable and happy with.  It would be an unusually detail-oriented and picky person who would even notice that in your record when you are applying for positions, let alone care.

Comment: @R.AS., why are you doing your references by hand? This is a place where a citation manager (EndNote, BibTeX, etc) comes in handy. They handle the formatting both of the citation in the text and at the end or as a footnote through formulas that understand and can format to the proper style for each set of formatting guidelines (like Harvard or APA). They even let you switch at will.

Comment: @Jakebeal but technically speaking, can Harvard be used for business studies? I mean, it's the 'general' form of author-date referencing style and since APA is a variant of it and used in business, therefore Harvard can be used, is my logic in place?

Comment: @BillBarth I am not sure, I just like to handle my stuff manually since I am too picky about details, is that a poor (or inefficient) practice?

Comment: @R.AS., I think so, but I've never seen BibTeX, my personal choice, and LaTeX get a citation really, really, horribly wrong, nor have I had a paper returned by a journal for my citations not matching their in-house style.